# Change text color of UIColorPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

I do not see any way to change the text color for a `UIColorPickerViewController`. Otherwise it's perfect for my needs and would prefer to use it versus making my own picker. I have a light and dark theme for my app and is important that I match the theme.

I've tried the usual hacks like:

```
myPickerView.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "textColor")
```

But it's not key `textColor` compliant and crashes.

Changing the tint color changes the eyedropper icon but no text:

```
myPickerView.view.tintColor = .cyan
```

The `toolbarItems` property is nil.

I tried overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle`:

```
class MyUIColorPickerViewController:UIColorPickerViewController {   
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .darkContent
    }
}
```

It has a `navigationItem` property, but all of its' properties are nil and `navigationController` is nil.

I tried looking at all the subviews of its subviews, but nothing. Seems like there must be a way. Sad Apple doesn't provide us very basic control over its appearance.

Comment: "I have a light and dark theme for my app and is important that I match the theme" All the built-in VCs should match the user interface style automatically. Do you have your own dark and light themes, which overrides the user's system preference?

Comment: If so, how about `myPickerView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark`?

Comment: I have my own themes based on the user's setting that predates the system. I was not aware of `.overrideUserInterfaceStyle`, but that does the trick, thank you! If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just to match your own custom dark and light themes, you can set [`overrideUserInterfaceStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3238087-overrideuserinterfacestyle) on the color picker view controller to the matching `.light`/`.dark` value.

```
// when in your own dark mode
myPickerView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```